# Assert Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#

I have this assertion and it throws me an error even when count is 0.

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Count==0,String.Format("It could not be opened for {0} topic, starting with {1}"list.Count,list[0]));
```

I find it strange because since the assertion is true, then why is the message still being evaluated? or am i missing sth here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I find it strange because since the assertion is true, then why is the message still being evaluated?

Because `IsTrue` is a method of the Assert class. The compiler evaluates both arguments and then passes them to the function. Evaluating the second argument fails, before the function is even called.

Answer (score 0):

The `IsTrue` method and doesn't have short circuiting semantics like `&&` or `||`.  All of the arguments will be evaluated in order unless one of them throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

The message is evaluated before the assertion is called. It is a parameter that is sent to the IsTrue-method, so string.Format is called before.
There is no magic implementation that first evaluates the expression to be asserted and then builds the message only if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format` is executed before calling `Assert.IsTrue()` - hence it gives an error if the list is empty regardless of what `Assert.IsTrue()` does.

Note that this is the case for any function call in C#: all the parameters are evaluated first, and then the results of the evaluation are passed to the function.